# Memory Usage of SKSpriteNodes

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm making a tile-based adventure game in iOS. Currently my level data is stored in a 100x100 array. I'm considering two approaches for displaying my level data. The easiest approach would be to make an `SKSpriteNode` for each tile. However, I'm wondering if an iOS device has enough memory for 10,000 nodes. If not I can always create and delete nodes from the level data as needed.

Comment: no need to store all 10000 tiles in memory,  you have many approaches.  You could turn the 100x100 tiles into 1 huge sprite node, or you could cache the original texture tiles into memory,  create a tile set of how ever many tiles fit on the screen + 1 to the width and height, and keep swapping the textures of your nodes, instead of the sprites (so that you are not swapping tons of tiles, you can make the screen 1 mega tile, and just add tiles to the non visible areas, then after you scroll, you capture all the nodes to make it a new texture.  Sorry for the explanations

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Those approaches work and I have tried some of them. However, I'm generating random maps in the game and the functionality of SKNodes would make that easier. That's why I would like SKNodes for each individual tile.

Comment: why does it have to be SKNodes,  a random map could just be made with an Int array of 10,000 elements,  A lot less space than 10,000 SKNodes, or like I said, just turn it into 1 node with a huge texture (or a couple more if the size exceeds max texture)  You do not want to push your luck with  consuming all resources, remember iOS now has multi tasking with other apps,  you do not want to be consuming memory needlessly and causing all other apps to be forced into a suspended state

Comment: Ok so it would use too much memory. I'll go with my alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is meant to work with Tiled, but the code in there might help you optimize what you are looking to do. I have done my best to optimize for big maps like the one you are making. The big thing to look at is more so how you are creating textures I know that has been a big killer in the past.

Swift
https://github.com/SpriteKitAlliance/SKATiledMap

Object-C
https://github.com/SpriteKitAlliance/SKAToolKit

Both are designed to load in a JSON string too so there is a chance you could still generate random maps without having to use the Tiled Editor as long as you match the expected format.

Also you may want to consider looking at how culling works in the Objective-C version as we found more recently removing nodes from the parent has really optimized performance on iOS 9.

Hopefully you find some of that helpful and if you have any questions feel free to email me.

**Edit**

Another option would be to look at Object Pooling. The core concept is to create only sprites you need to display and when you are done store them in a collection of sorts. When you need a new sprite you ask the collection for one and if it doesn't have one you create a new one.

For example you need a grass tile and you ask for one and it doesn't have one that has been already created that is waiting to be used so it creates one. You may do this to fill a 9 x 7 grid to fill up your screen. As you move away grass that gets moved off screen gets tossed into the collection to be used again when the new row comes in and needs grass. This works really well if all you are doing is displaying tiles. Not so great if tiles have dynamic properties that need to be updated and are unique in nature.

Here is a great link even if it is for Unity =)

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling